# How to query User stories without a Task in Rally Custom Grid?

Tags: rally

As titled

I try to use the query

```
(Tasks.length = 0)
```

or

```
(Tasks = null)
```

but no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rally's WSAPI you cannot query an object based upon the content of a child collection.

This means that you cannot find stories that have no tasks or a specific task or anything like that. The same holds true for finding if a story has any children.

It is something we have played with internally but we don't have any solution to this issue on our short term backlog.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons this has made my life difficult as well. We had some of our team working on this for our last hackathon but it never made it to daylight. Don't forget to make the answer as accepted if it answers your question

Comment: not quite a solution to my question, but thank you for having been very helpful to me lately :)

Comment: It is the answer to your question though. I will find this and update it when we get a better answer for you.

Comment: I'll be looking forward to it

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are estimating your tasks - this grid query might work:

((CreationDate > 2012-5-01) AND (TaskEstimateTotal < 1))

Note I was using CreationDate to get a smaller set of stories, but you don't have to do that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use **Custom Grid** (Now it is called **Customer List** in Rally). If you want to do so follow these steps:

1. Build a report and use iteration as the filter. (Or not, based on your demand)
2. Add a customer list on this report.
3. Add Query (For Team A and Team B, you can add more teams if you need)

   `((TaskEstimateTotal < 1) AND ((Project.Name = "Team A") OR (Project.Name = "Team B"))`
4. Add two more filters to remove stories:

   a. `Task Status = NONE`
   (Remove stories which have tasks, but do not have estimates on the task level yet.)

   b. `Defect Status = None`
   (Remove stories which are using defects, not tasks)

Then you should have the report you need.